# How can i change an animated mesh, with pose

Tags: mesh, armature, pose-mode

I have an animation, but it is imported from ms3d file, the mesh is animated but the armature is not linked to the mesh

How can i change the animated mesh, is needed to link animated mesh with the armature ?

Comment: Are you sure there are no hidden armatures? meshes can only really move if paired to armatures or have shapekeys

Comment: yep, nothing hidden, just animation, but no conexions between them